# CURL created .zip won't open

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to create a .zip file from an asset from another server like so:

```
$url  = 'http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/butterfly.jpg';
$path = 'butterfly.zip'; 
$fp = fopen($path, 'w'); 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

After I run the script I see the .zip on my server.  When I download the .zip and try to open it on my Windows computer I get this error:

**Windows cannot open the folder**
The compressed (zipped) folder 'butterfly.zip' is invalid.

Anybody have an idea why it won't open?

**UPDATE**

I understand my mistake here.  I can see how my original code was just saving the .jpg as a .zip, instead of putting the .jpg in an archived (zipped) folder.

Comment: Just renaming a jpg to a zip does not make it a zip...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to do this:

```
// if you have fopen wrappers forget about curl. way to complex for something simple
$jpg = file_get_contents('http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/butterfly.jpg');
$jpgName ='butterfly.jpg';

//use the built in zip functionality in php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open("c:\temp\$jpgName.zip" , ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open c:\temp\$jpgName.zip\n");
}
$zip->addFromString($jpgName, $jpg);
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are downloading a JPEG file (.jpg) and are saving it as a .zip file.  Naturally, if you try to open this ZIP file as an archive, it will fail, because the content of the file is an image, not an archive.  If you want to actually create a zip archive containing this jpg image, then you need to download the image and then use [ZIP family of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) to compress it.

Comment: I was confused.  I thought it was automatically putting the file in an archive for me. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

If I was understood correctly, you are trying to open .jpeg file as .zip. Try to open this zip file using image viewer.